# Replace column value with another column's value conditionally perl

Tags: perl, split, conditional-statements

I am working with multiple files of very large data delimited by tab.  It is very important that every row has a date but some contain only a value of '0'.  Within the file, there is an additional date column that can be used if the desired date column is '0'.  How do I replace the columns with the '0' value with the value of the additional date column? My example data is below.

```
ID  NAME    Desired_Date    Additional_Date
1234    jimbob  0   12/23/2014
2345    joejohn 12/30/2014  12/31/2014
```

Further below is my desired output:

```
ID  NAME    Desired_Date    Additional_Date
1234    jimbob  12/23/2014  12/23/2014
2345    joejohn 12/30/2014  12/31/2014
```

So as you can see, I would like to copy over additional date where desired date is '0'.  I have some code I tried but it does not seem to be doing the trick.

```
while (<>) {
    my @F = split;
    if ($F[2] == 0) {
        print $F[2] = $F[3];
    }
}
print "@F\n";
```

The current output is:

```
Desired_date12/23/2014
```

Comment: You need to use `==` for comparison, `=` is the assignment operator. [`perlop#Equality`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators)

Comment: @HunterMcMillen when I use  if ($F[2] == 0) instead of  if ($F[2] = 0) I get "Desired_date12/23/2014" as my output and the rest of the data is blown away.  It is still identifying that $F[2] has a value of '0' but is not simply moving the Desired_date filed over.

Comment: If you update the code in the question, it will a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems with your code:

1. When the field is `0`, you should just copy the alternate value - not also print the result of the assignment.
2. You need to print every line you read (regardless of whether you modify it. Your current `print "@F\n"` is outside the loop, so it will only run once.

Working code:

```
while (<>) {
    my @F = split;
    if ($F[2] == 0) {
        $F[2] = $F[3];
    }
    print join("\t", @F) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Of course!!  Re-join after the split!  Works great!

Comment: one more question.  Say if the data had empty fields i.e. ('2345',\t','\t','joejohn') and the empty field is omitted and bumps back i.e. ('2345','\t','joejohn').  Is there any way to prevent this?